# Appropriate transformation for model that is overestimating on low probabilities

Tags: r, model

I have a model which is overestimating low probabilities as per the chart below.  I know that if it was underfitting there I could apply a sigmoidal transformation.  The current model I have appears to be instable and whilst it doubles my prediction rate (of a low frequency event) I am some what reluctant to use it in its current state.

The chart is comparing the event probabilities against binned predicted probabilities.

I've posted this here as this is an R question as well as a stats question.

Any thoughts?  [image]
J

Comment: Do you have a specific R-code question? It appears you don't so I m voting for this to be migrated to Cross Validated

Comment: "a model" is way to broad. You'll have to be way more specific than that.

Comment: "Any thoughts?" is also a very broad question. It seems unlikely to me anyone could give you correct and precise advise here, other than some hand waiving.

Comment: This is generated from a random forest and the any thoughts is only a sign off. The request is for a transformation that adjusts this result so that it brings it more along the 45degree line which is what a good and stable  model would do